# Modify code - translation

Tags: source-code

Can you give me tips, how I can get the blender open source code, change text field to the Russian translation and publish it as an kind of addon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender already comes with translations. Open Blender's preferences (*Edit > Preferences*) and go to the *Interface* tab. There you can enabled the checkbox for the *Translation* option and select the desired language. The *Automatic* option will use your OS language configuration.

[image: Preferences]

[image: Russian option]

You have the option to enable *Tooltip* to translate the tooltips that appear when you hover over UI items, *Interface* to translate all labels in the interface and *New Data* to translate data-blocks such as material and object names.